# Maintaining salary history for the employee sql

Tags: oracle

I am new in oracle, i am trying to maintain the salary history for all the employee in hr employee table which have position and salary.
How to maintain the salary history for all the employee if every year employee receives a salary increase of 1% EVERY YEAR  and all the employee are still working , so that i can keep track of historical salary for the employees.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a trigger on table employees, which could save row to aby hist table ( for example employee_hist)

Answer (score 0):

Design wise I would create a salary table that can have multiple entries per employee.  When you want to know current salary, you do a join and query the most recent record.  This preserves not only the salary number but any other data in the record such as who entered it.  It also lets you easily fix mistakes by just deleting the incorrect record and the current salary query will fall back to the old one.

Comment: Thanks, I will design the table with this concept.